# Updating PyQt4 GUI while in loop

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt4, qthread

I would like to show progress of calculation if in my GUI. To do so I would like to update my PyQt4 label each time a calculation is made. I know that I am supposed to use thread to do it, but it doesn't work. Nothing changes, and after while loop is complete, the label is updated to "100%".Even though the thread is working the value still won't update smoothly. There are comments in my code explaining what is what. Please help me :)

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import time

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    trigger = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, progress, parent=None):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.progress = progress #progress is a PyQt4 label object

    def update_progress(self, value):
        self.progress.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Progress: %s " % value, None))
        print "I was called", value
        print self.progress #prints <PyQt4.QtGui.QLabel object at 0x0000000008151708>
        #as you can see the object is passed all right
    def run(self, value):
        self.trigger.emit(value)

class Calculus:
    def __init__(self):
        print "object created"

    @staticmethod
    def euler(b,h,progress):    
        #progress is a PyQt4 label object, b and h are some integers
        actions_done = 0
        actions_number = b / h

        thread = MyThread(progress)#create a thread
        thread.trigger.connect(thread.update_progress)#connect it with a update function
        thread.start()#start the thread


        while t <= b:
            actions_done+=1
            progress_value = (actions_done/actions_number)*100

            thread.run(progress_value)#emit signal?
            t += h

        thread.terminate()
```

@EDIT, here is my solution but with memory leaking problem

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Calculus:
    def __init__(self):
        print "object created"

    @staticmethod
    def update_progress(self,value,ui_object): 
        ui_object.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Progress: %s %%" % value, None))

        #MEMORY LEAK WHEN UPDATING TOO MUCH (H=0.0001 AND B=1000)
        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents() #update gui for pyqt



    @staticmethod
    def euler(b,h,progress):
        actions_done = 0
        actions_number = b * (1./h) #t = t+h. When h = 0.01 we need to perform t=t+h 100(1/h) times to get 1. 
                                    #when t varies from 0 to b, then we need to multiply this 1 * b(end time)
                                    #so we get b * (1/h) as a number of actions to perform

        scale = actions_number * 0.01

        while t <= b:
            actions_done+=1
            progress_value = (actions_done/actions_number)*100

            if (actions_done % scale == 0):
                Calculus.update_progress(None,progress_value, progress)         

            t += h
```

Comment: If you want to know why your updated code leaks memory, I suggest you ask about it in a new question. However, I strongly recommend you go back to threads, and implement the answer I provided. Threads are designed to have long running code in them, while leaving the GUI responsive in the main thread. Using `processEvents()` is a really just a hack to keep your GUI responsive.

Comment: Yes that's what I am about to do. You're answer in fact gave me some insight into how it really should be done and why. Thank you for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `thread.run()` in the way that you are does not do what you think it does. Currently it is simply executing the `thread.run()` method in the main thread.

It is the call to `thread.start()` which starts the thread, and automatically calls the `thread.run()` method. As such, you need the while loop **inside** the `thread.run()` method.

This is because you want to pass complete control over to the thread, and finish the `euler` method so that control can be returned to the GUI event loop (so it can process redraws, and the method to update the progress bar) as soon as possible. You should not be trying to manage the threads execution from the main thread.

Comment: I have solved this problem by updating my control and then using processEvents() inside my while loop, but when this loop is long enough (for instance 1000000 times) i get memory leak - my programs starts to eat a huge amount of RAM. Any idea why? :P

Comment: @Zwierzak Not without seeing your new code, no. But it still sounds like you are using threads incorrectly. Did you understand what I wrote?

Comment: Yea i got this, but putting that while loop inside Thread's run method seems like a bad idea, because this loop sometimes works for like 1 minute before completing the task. I guess it's a bad idea to put such a long loop isnide a thread. I have updates my post with my solution I made so far.

Comment: @Zwierzak but that is exactly what Threads are for: Process something that takes a very long time. If you put this load in a Thread your gui keeps responsive and has nothing to do with managing the computation. You should put the while loop in your Thread and emit a Signal with the progression info for every loop step.